# Laravel console only app, disable routes and views

Tags: laravel, console-application

I am working on a "command line" application which features all the Laravel Features (console, database, storages etc..), but I would like to remove all HTTP Controllers, Views and Routes.

What is the most effective way to do this?

Comment: sounds like you might be looking for Laravel Zero https://laravel-zero.com/ "Micro-framework for console applications"

Comment: You can just remove route files and the extra HTTP files.

Comment: From a full Laravel Installation, just removing the http files and route files are not enough. 
I'll give laravel-zero a try.

Answer (score 0):

I will use Laravel Zero for the moment. It seems best suited for the task; it has also a `build` process, where as a result a single file can be deployed.

https://laravel-zero.com

***Remark:***
I tried shrinking a full Laravel installation, but that didn't seems to be so straight forward as just removing views, controllers and stuff.